# How to scroll to the last position (item 10) of the table on the top of the DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code -

```
<div id="scroll-pane" style="width:250px; height:100px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
      <table>
        <tr><td>item 0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 10</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Javascript code -

```
var divEl = document.getElementById("scroll-pane");
var selectedTrEl = undefined;

function select(index) {
    var trEl = divEl.getElementsByTagName("tr")[index];
    if(selectedTrEl) {
        selectedTrEl.className = "";
    }
    selectedTrEl = trEl;
    selectedTrEl.className = "selected";
    var scrollTo = selectedTrEl.offsetTop;
    divEl.scrollTop = scrollTo;
}

select(10);
```

JS example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7a960tdr/1/

I want that item 10 show in the top of the div, but seems I've to do something else to do it.

Comment: Do you want the item 10 be scrolled up showing nothing above it or be really the first element?

Comment: It will automatically if you have more elements on the page beneath `<tr><td>item 10</td></tr>`. Now it should not as 10 is the last element among the items!

Comment: if am right you show only <tr><td> item 10</td></tr> record on scroll

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element 10 being scrolled up the first, you will need to add something on the bottom to elevate it, you may want to make the last element bigger than the others so there'll be white space on the bottom of the scrollable list. I don't know if margin or padding will make the work too.

Comment: Yes, padding at the last element should work. Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/7a960tdr/2/).

Comment: Awolf, this is good. but just for the last item, what if i want to top the 9 item?

Comment: AllanJack, it will still working, the ninth item will be scrolled to the top of the box and the tenth item will be just below. Or are you looking for another behaviour? You could modify by script the padding up to the selected element position, so if it is the ninth I can apply 90px instead 100px.